# Laptop overclock

Tags: laptop, temperature, dell-inspiron

Is it usual to a laptop made by dell (inspiron N4050) with i5 processor have the processor running at 3.0 GHz without any overclock settings?

The temperature surpass 80 ºC sometimes.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it's running at that speed?

Comment: Do you mean that it's running at 3.0 GHz constantly? Or only when under a heavy workload? If the latter, then that's normal - Intel's Core i5 and i7 CPUs can dynamically overclock (a feature known as [Turbo Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost)), and several i5 models can reach 3.0 GHz and beyond.

Comment: Both AIDA and windows 8 task manager says that

Comment: That would be it so, since I was installing an OS on VM